# Lizmap "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource." Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: installation, ubuntu, qgis-server, apache, lizmap

After installing QGIS Server and the Lizmap Webclient I am encountering the error

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

when trying to access http://serverip/lizmap.

### My Setup:

- Ubuntu 20.04 with php 7.4 and the current apache2 webserver
- QGIS-Server in the current ltr version (3.22.10)
- Lizmap Webclient 3.5.5 downloaded from github release and installed according to the instructions

### QGIS-Server:

My QGIS-Server is up and I get the following xml message, so I am assuming its functional:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" xmlns:qgs="http://www.qgis.org/wms" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/sld_capabilities.xsd http://www.qgis.org/wms http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetSchemaExtension" version="1.3.0">
<Service>
<Name>WMS</Name>
<Title>Untitled</Title>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword vocabulary="ISO">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi" xlink:type="simple"/>
<Fees>None</Fees>
<AccessConstraints>None</AccessConstraints>
</Service>
<Capability>
<Request>
<GetCapabilities>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetCapabilities>
<GetMap>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=16bit</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=8bit</Format>
<Format>image/png; mode=1bit</Format>
<Format>application/dxf</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetMap>
<GetFeatureInfo>
<Format>text/plain</Format>
<Format>text/html</Format>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml</Format>
<Format>application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1</Format>
<Format>application/json</Format>
<Format>application/geo+json</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</GetFeatureInfo>
<sld:GetLegendGraphic>
<Format>image/jpeg</Format>
<Format>image/png</Format>
<Format>application/json</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</sld:GetLegendGraphic>
<sld:DescribeLayer>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</sld:DescribeLayer>
<qgs:GetStyles>
<Format>text/xml</Format>
<DCPType>
<HTTP>
<Get>
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://serverip/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?" xlink:type="simple"/>
</Get>
</HTTP>
</DCPType>
</qgs:GetStyles>
</Request>
<Exception>
<Format>XML</Format>
</Exception>
<sld:UserDefinedSymbolization RemoteWFS="0" UserLayer="0" SupportSLD="1" UserStyle="1" RemoteWCS="0" InlineFeature="0"/>
<Layer queryable="0">
<Title>Untitled</Title>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword vocabulary="ISO">infoMapAccessService</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<westBoundLongitude>-0.000001</westBoundLongitude>
<eastBoundLongitude>0.000001</eastBoundLongitude>
<southBoundLatitude>-0.000001</southBoundLatitude>
<northBoundLatitude>0.000001</northBoundLatitude>
</EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox maxy="0.001" miny="-0.001" maxx="0.001" CRS="EPSG:3857" minx="-0.001"/>
<BoundingBox maxy="0.000001" miny="-0.000001" maxx="0.000001" CRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-0.000001"/>
</Layer>
</Capability>
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

### Lizmap

I followed the instruction in the lizmap documentation for the apache2 configuration with slight modification for php7.4 and then installed lizmap from the .zip file as described there.

I haven't installed PostgreSQL, pure-ftpd and Spatialite as the documentation states that these are optional.

I also assigned the rights for the webdirectory (/var/www/lizmap/..) as described in the documentation.

After I encountered the issue I realized I hadn't setup a vhost file for lizmap since this is **not** stated in the official documentation. I found this French site and created + activated the vhost file according to the instructions. Then I repeated the whole right assignment section.

However, the issue still persists.

### Lizmap vhost - lizmap.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName lizmap
        DocumentRoot /var/www/thermodata/lizmap/www
        <Directory /var/www/thermodata>
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_lizmap.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_lizmap.log combined
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

### QGIS-Server vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/">
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
        </Directory>


        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

### Apache2

I assume that this is an apache2 issue, however when I followed the instruction on https://www.tecmint.com/forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server-error/ nothing changed and the config file has the correct content.

### Apache2 config file:

```
# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
#Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# The directory where shm and other runtime files will be stored.
#

DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>
# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent



# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
StartServers       4
MinSpareThreads    25
MaxSpareThreads    100
ThreadLimit          64
ThreadsPerChild      25
MaxClients        150
MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

What else could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, I just ran sudo for every command in the installation documentation and that solved it. I can access the Lizmap interface now.